# Glusterfs fuse client consuming high memory - memory leak

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, glusterfs

I have set up my glusterfs cluster as Striped-Replicated on GCP Servers, but I am facing memory leak issue with Glusterfs fuse client. Its memory consumption is increasing every day.

Both glusterfs server and glusterfs fuse client is using the latest version(Client-4.1.5, Server- 4.1), but the below process is consuming high memory on the client servers.

```
glusterfs --fopen-keep-cache=off --volfile-server=gluster1 --volfile-id=/+
```

Every day I can see that memory consumption of the above process is increasing, a temporary fix is to unmount and kill the process.

In my glusterfs client server, I am getting 'Stale File Handle error'. Not sure this error caused the memory leak.

[2018-10-21 04:08:46.921985] W [fuse-bridge.c:1201:fuse_setattr_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 3705309: SETATTR() /Production/example.com/wp-content/cache/wpsol-cache/4bd4f0bf132901ecb17261f388864fd3 => -1 (Stale file handle)

Also, my glusterfs server is using default settings. Please help if there is any patches or fix.

Comment: please report the error to the glusterfs client project/vendor

Comment: It seems to be some memory leak issue,already they are aware of.